# Не получается вставить формула массива во все строки конкретного столбца, при условии что кол-во строк в таблице волатильно (Vba Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub AAAAA()

Dim строка As Long
For строка = 6 To Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            Cells(строка, "N").Select
            Selection.FormulaArray = _
                "=INDEX('[ГДО — Л-СЗНП.xlsx]ГДО'!R12C11:R14C11,MATCH(RC[-11]:R[5]C[-11]&RC[7]:R[5]C[7]&RC[8]:R[5]C[8]&RC[9]:R[5]C[9],'[ГДО — Л-СЗНП.xlsx]ГДО'!R12C4:R14C4&'[ГДО — Л-СЗНП.xlsx]ГДО'!R12C8:R14C8&'[ГДО — Л-СЗНП.xlsx]ГДО'!R12C9:R14C9&'[ГДО — Л-СЗНП.xlsx]ГДО'!R12C10:R14C10,0))"
  
Next строка

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Для ввода формулы массива в диапазон не нужен цикл (но возникнет ошибка из-за длины формулы, см. пункт 2 ниже):

```
Sub BBBBB()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range(.Cells(6, "N"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).FormulaArray = _
                    "=INDEX('[ГДО — Л-СЗНП.xlsx]ГДО'!R12C11:R14C11,MATCH(RC[-11]:R[5]C[-11]&RC[7]:R[5]C[7]&RC[8]:R[5]C[8]&RC[9]:R[5]C[9],'[ГДО — Л-СЗНП.xlsx]ГДО'!R12C4:R14C4&'[ГДО — Л-СЗНП.xlsx]ГДО'!R12C8:R14C8&'[ГДО — Л-СЗНП.xlsx]ГДО'!R12C9:R14C9&'[ГДО — Л-СЗНП.xlsx]ГДО'!R12C10:R14C10,0))"
    End With
End Sub
```

2. Длина формулы в формуле массива ограничена 255 символами. В вашей формуле 269 символов. Поэтому возникает ошибка. Это можно легко проверить, например, с помощью кода:

```
Sub test()
    On Error GoTo out
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
        For i = 250 To 260
            frml = "=""" & String(i, "A") & """"
            .Offset(i - 250, 3) = Len(frml) & " символов"
            .Resize(, 3).Offset(i - 250).FormulaArray = frml
        Next
out:
        .Resize(, 3).Offset(i - 250) = "#ОШИБКА!"
    End With
End Sub
```

3. Решить проблему в данном случае можно, сократив имя файла `ГДО — Л-СЗНП`, например, до трех символов. Или другим способом уменьшить длину формулы до <=255 символов.